# Magento: Display custom product price in product listing, view page and also set same price after adding product to cart

Tags: magento

I need to display custom price for each product where the admin will set different price for each product. and this product price only should be displayed in product listing and product view page, without changing the product actual price. And also the same price should apply to the cart. I tried with catalog_product_get_final_price observer, but It shows the price as special price but it will not change the display of product price. Please give me an idea, how can I do this? Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
on list page and view page just check whether your custom price is null nor not if it is null show original price and if it not null show custom price.

create a event in config file **checkout_cart_product_add_after** as given below

<events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
          <observers>
                <unique_event_name>
                  <class>modulename/observer</class>
                  <method>modifyPrice</method>
                  </unique_event_name>
            </observers>
      </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
</events>


create new file **Observer.php**


    class namespace_modulename_Model_Observer

      {

          public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
             {
                 // Get the quote item

                 $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();

                 // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one

                 $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

                 // Load the custom price

                 $price = $this->_getPriceByItem($item);

                 // Set the custom price

                 $item->setCustomPrice($price);

                 $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);

                 // Enable super mode on the product.

                 $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

             }


             protected function _getPriceByItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
             {
                 $price;

                 //use $item to determine your custom price.

                 return $price;
             }
                }
```

Comment: Yeah, This is a good idea. But In case of Configurable and Bundled products, On selecting the custom options It shows the default price in product view page. How can I set custom price on selection of custom options.

Comment: on product add to cart event you will get an id of the product and from that product id you can load price of that product

Comment: That's right, We can get the product id and set custom price for the cart item. But, My question was on selecting options, the price will change using js function on product view page. And In my case the price was not changing even after selecting different options. Anyhow I solved this problem now. Thanks to all for your ideas and suggestions.